# Table names with spaces - PYMSSQL and MSSQL

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pymssql

I am using pymssql python library to connect to a MS SQL database to extract data.

Everything works fine until I encounter a table name with a space.

That is the code below works fine

```
import pymssql
conn = pymssql.connect(
  server="11.11.11.11",
  port=1433,
  user="######",
  password="######",
  database="######")
cursor = conn.cursor(as_dict=True)
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Students')
```

while this code will not

```
import pymssql
conn = pymssql.connect(
  server="11.11.11.11",
  port=1433,
  user="######",
  password="######",
  database="######")
cursor = conn.cursor(as_dict=True)
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM  [Students Info]')
```

I have tried using " and ` to enclose but the error I receive is constantly

> "Invalid object name 'Students Info'.DB-Lib error message 208,
>   severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL
>   Server\n")

I have tried multiple tables with spaces and they consistently give this error.

I have also tried the following from the CLI

```
tsql -H 11.11.11.11 -p 1433 -U ####### -P ########
1> select * from [Students Info]
2> go
```

and the error has been

> Msg 208 (severity 16, state 1) from DAYMAP Line 1:    "Invalid object
>   name 'Student Info'."

Comment: in the CLI you wrote table name wrong should be `[Students Info]` not `[Student Info]` see `s` in `Student`

Comment: Thank you. But they are pseudo table names and do not impact on the actual end result.

Comment: what you mean with pseudo table names? are somewhat not real tables or you just redacted the code?

Comment: What SQL Server version are you using? I'm unable to recreate in 2014. I'll start an answer to show you what I've done.

Answer (score 1):

To trying to reproduce this error, I first created a table and inserted some data:

```
CREATE TABLE [bad idea] (
    [bad idea column] VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO [bad idea] ([bad idea column]) VALUES ('Spaces in DB entity names are generally a bad idea.')
```

Then, from tsql, I can query it:

```
1> SELECT * FROM [bad idea]
2> GO
Spaces in DB entity names are generally a bad idea.
```

Are you sure you've got the column names spelled correctly? Can you share the exact column names you're redacting - are they all ASCII characters, for example? And what SQL Server version are you connecting to? Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The three examples of exact table names are Advanced Scales, All Running Records and Transition Scales. I am aware that spaces in DBs are generally a bad idea and am just trying to read it out. I will check the version asap and post below.